# How to undo an accidental card description deletion?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Upon editing a Trello card description, Trello selects the whole text, which makes it pretty easy to accidentally delete the whole description and save it.

I have accidentally done this a few times, but unlike when editing the title of the card, Trello doesn't seem to log card description updates. How can I revert such an accidental deletion of potentially important infos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the card and add ".json" to the end of the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)
2. You're now facing the "raw data" of everything Trello knows about this card. It's JSON-formatted data and it's pretty hard to read for a human, so it might come handy to either [pretty-print it](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print), use [a JSON viewer extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh), or use Firefox that prettify JSON by default (like I do)
3. The description edition should be under the "action" key. Just scroll down to it and locate the action containing the whole deleted text
4. You can now copy-paste it back into the card description. Accident undone!

[image: card before accidental deletion]

[image: card during deletion]

[image: add JSON to the URL]

[image: JSON data]

Comment: I have accidentally lost focus of the comment field and kept typing, which resulted in an unwanted change of the title of the card. It was frustrating to feel helpless in retrieving the original title, but your solution worked like a charm, thank you very much! Also, Firefox pretty prints JSON by default nowadays. :)